# Clarification on function signature and dispatching behaviour in julia

Tags: julia, typing, dispatch

I was trying out some things in the Julia (1.2) REPL and I stuck my mind on something I don't understand about dispatching.

---

I first tried this thing which is working the way I expected:

`f(a::T) where {T <: Int} = "Test"`

- Calling f(3) works since `Int <: Int == true`
- Calling f("Hello") results in an "MethodError: no method matching" error since `String <: Int == false`

---

Then, I tried this method, and I don't understand why calling it works in some case:

`f(a::T, b::U) where {T, U <: T} = "Another Test"`

- Calling f(3, 3) works (as I expected)
- BUT f(3, "Hello") also works and does not throw a "MethodError: no method matching" ???

I thought that (since T becomes an Int and U a String) `String <: Int == false` ???

---

I guess I am missing something pretty straightforward here but I can't find it...
So this is my question, why f(3, "Hello") is working???

---

Moreover, I tried this snippet of code (i tried to recreate the second method signature) and it correctly fails as I expected:

`Test = Tuple{T, U} where {T, U <: T}`

`Test{Int, String}` (this fails as i expected with "TypeError: in Type, in U, expected U<:Int64, got Type{String}")

Comment: I can't reproduce your last definition of f() returning `Int64,String,false`. You might need to restart Julia if you add methods to functions. Just use a new character e.g. `h` for a new test.
To your question: It appears that the system tries to find _any_ solution to the type restriction, and `T=Any, U=Any where U:<T` is one. If you introduce a concrete type as in your third example it works as expected. People with a sounder Julia type system knowledge will soon give a proper answer to this.

Comment: Oh! You're right, i needed to restart Julia... My redefinition with T<: Int did not override the last one with only T (without any warning...). And your answer about the system finding Any as a solution for T and U explains everything! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [laborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138606/laborg) it seems I now understand what was going on. If we take this method:

`f(a::T, b::U) where {T, U <: T} = "Another Test"`

- 'T' is the "UnionAll" aka "Iterated Union" of all possible types  of 'a'.
- 'U' is the "UnionAll" aka "Iterated Union" of all possible types  of 'b' that are subtypes of 'T'
- What I was misunderstanding was the fact that if (example) a::Int, then T can take a parent abstract type of typeof(a). Since Int <: Any, then T = Any is a valid solution for dispatch.
- The same for U = Any since String <: Any.

So we now have U <: T that resolves to Any <: Any == true, and the method is called!

I hope I get it :)

Answer (score 4):

What's happening here is that `T`can be a datatype and `U` can be any supertype of string. This the conditions are fulfilled. The thing that was tripping you up with string not being a subtype of int is a red herring since no concrete type is the subtype of any other.

Comment: And why with the Tuple definition instead it rises the error ?